# Show/Hide DIV control with buttons

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a menu bar that I want to control the visibility of DIV's featuring varied content. Currently the DIV's visiblity and invisibility is controlled but clicking on the same button. What I want to do is enable any button selected in the menu to make the previous DIV invisible and replace it with the selected DIV's visibility.

Is this possible???
The script that I'm using to call up the DIV is as follows:

```
 <"javascript:unhide('unique DIV id goes here');">
```

Any help appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What has been tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the `display` property. Some general stuff:

- If you want is to hide - `visibility: hidden \ visible`
- If you want to replace - `display: none \ block`

The difference is that in `display` the element stops taking up space in the page, and in `visibility` they do take space, but you don't see them.

So try this:

```
function unhide(id){
   document.getElementById(id).display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: You just forgot the quotes around the value of property: `document.getElementById(id).display = 'none';`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Apologies but I'm a bit confused. Which of these, if either should I have in my CSS: 
<.hidden { display: none; }
 .unhidden { display: block; }> 

or

< .hidden { visibility: hidden; }
 .unhidden { visibility: visible; }>

Also this is the current script I'm using:

< function unhide(divID) {
 var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 if (item) {
 item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
 }
 }>

Should I replace it with your suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: @DavidKneale please, pay attention to what he wrote on the begining of the answer: `visibility: hidden` hides the element but still take up its space and `display: none` hides the element and don't take up its space, almost like removing it from the page.

Comment: @DavidKneale Well I'm not really sure I understood what you want to do, so I guess its `display: none`, but you can just try it out. Or you can take a minute to see [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm) or [this](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13638) to get the idea of that each dose.

Comment: @Martin I'm pretty sure what you're instructing is correct, I'm just implementing something wrong somewhere! In my CSS I have the following:  
<}  
.hidden { display: none; }  
 .unhidden { display: block; }>  
In the document head I have this script:   
<function unhide(id){  
   document.getElementById(id).display = 'none';  
}>   
The a href is: <javascript:unhide('DIV id goes here');>  
  
The development page is <http://www.worldchallenge-internationalschools.com/dev/asia.html>    
Click on the 'Expeditions' tab and 'Africa'.  
Apologies for not understanding this more clearly.  
Thanks

Comment: Well, if you really wrote something like `<{ .hidden{ display: none; }>` then you should may be search google for an HTML tutorial. This may seem a lot at the beginning, but after a day of head-banging you should get the idea.. Besides - on the page I see just `Bad request` with nothing else...